# PHP script is not able to execute specific python code in server, where all other files are executed

Tags: php, python, linux, raspberry-pi

**Here is my php code on server**

`/var/www/html/index.php`

```php
<body>
<?php   $level=shell_exec('python /home/pi/ultra.py');
    $test=shell_exec('echo "Hello"');
?>
<h1> The Water depth is : <?php echo $level; ?> </h1>
<h2> Printing Hello : <?php echo $test; ?> </h2>
</body>
```

the output of the above is as
[The output of index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pINS.png)

**The ultra.py code is here:**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

TRIG = 23
ECHO = 24

#print "Distance Measurement In Progress"
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
#print "Waiting For Sensor To Settle"
#time.sleep(2)
GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
#time.sleep(0.00001)
GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0:
  pulse_start = time.time()
while GPIO.input(ECHO)==1:
  pulse_end = time.time()
pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
distance = pulse_duration * 17150
distance = round(distance, 2)
h= distance/100
#print "Distance:",distance,"cm"
print h
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Now the problem is, php script is able to run any command or execute any program in server, but not this python script. I am stuck here.

Comment: Can you run the python script from command line executed as the user running the php script ? do you get any error when you run it ?

Comment: I run python script from command line and it executed perfectly. No errors.
And the /home/pi/ultra.py permossions are set to 777.

Comment: Are you running the script with the same user that is executing your web server ? I

Comment: Well, one thing i do notice is that i see no variable declarations for 'L' or 'G'

Comment: I am running the script with the same user, that executing my web server

Comment: @zack6849 
I forgot to change the variable names while uploading the code, actually variable level in the place of 'l' and variable 'test' in the place of 'g'.
The problem is same still.

Comment: After some experiments, I found that the problem is with GPIO commands in python script. PHP is not able to exicute python scripts with GPIO functions. Can any one help me to solve this problem? I am stuck here.